# join table with duplicate field names without alias

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Warning: edge case proceeds...

let's say you have a join between Customers and Orders

```
select * from Customers
join Orders on Customers.Id = Orders.CustomerId
```

This sql is being generated dynamically through a class library (dll) and the only access a user will have is the asterisk '*'. So they can put in field names, expressions, sub selects, etc.

They don't know what the table names will be because that is generated too. The problem is a case where there is a field name that is duplicated on both tables but the user can't refer to the one in right table of join because they don't have access to table names or aliases. **Is there another way the user can distinguish between duplicated field names using just the text area?**

*Additional Background Information:*
This is an ASP.NET web application where the user is presented with one text area so they can specify the fields they want to see in the result set. When the user presses enter to submit reply to the server, a class library (which developer has no control over) will generate every part of the sql statement except what fields the user inputs in that text area and then that is integrated into sql generator.

Comment: Can you show how this query generating?

Comment: help us with more Information, who generate the code?

Comment: surprise it is working for me `declare @tempA table
(ID int, name nvarchar(22))

insert into @tempA values (1,'PQR')
insert into @tempA values (1,'PQR')
insert into @tempA values (1,'XYZ')


declare @tempB table
(ID int, name nvarchar(22))

insert into @tempB values (1,'PQR')
insert into @tempB values (1,'PQR')
insert into @tempB values (1,'XYZ')


select * from 
@tempA A join @tempB B on A.ID = B.ID`

Comment: ok with the last update i think the best things is to create a view, and do a query over it

Comment: @tinka that's because you put `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT id, name` (without table name/alias) as requested by the OP. if you put the field list it is not working and produces the error `Ambiguous column name '[column name here]'.`

Comment: @Paolo ohh yes thanks

Comment: with a benefit comes a cost.  to support this type of querying, you have to have each field have a unique field name.

Comment: I figured as much, but just wanted to check to be sure.

Comment: Do you have any control over how the class library is invoked? E.g. rather than it doing the Customers/Orders join in your example, can you ask it to generate a SQL statement that queries a view on the server? (As @MattiaCaputo suggests above.)

Comment: No control over how invoked.